# Dynamic Listener Rules creation Type error

Tags: typescript, amazon-web-services, pulumi

**Config data:**

```
config:
  pulumi-ecs-stack:listener_rules_data:
    0:
      pathPattern:
        - "/login/*"
        - "/auth/*"
        - "/info/*"
```

**My script:**

```
import * as pulumi from "@pulumi/pulumi";
import * as aws from "@pulumi/aws";
import * as awsx from "@pulumi/awsx";

const config = new pulumi.Config()
const listener_rules_data = JSON.parse(config.require("listener_rules_data"))
// ...
var i = 0
for (var key in listener_rules_data) {
    let configuration = {
        listenerArn: httpsListener.arn,
        priority: i,
        actions: [{
            type: "forward",
        }],
        conditions: {},
    }
    for (let item in listener_rules_data[key]) {
        configuration.conditions = [
            {[item]: {values: listener_rules_data[key][item]}}
        ]
    }
    new aws.lb.ListenerRule(project_name + '-https-rule-' + i++, configuration);
}
```

> error: Running program '/repo/pulumi-ecs-stack' failed with an unhandled exception:
> TSError: ⨯ Unable to compile TypeScript:
> index.ts(80,61): error TS2345: Argument of type '{ listenerArn: pulumi.Output; priority: number; actions: { type: string; }[]; conditions: {}; }' is not assignable to parameter of type 'ListenerRuleArgs'.
> Types of property 'conditions' are incompatible.
> Type '{}' is not assignable to type 'Input<Input[]>'.
> Type '{}' is missing the following properties from type 'OutputInstance<Input[]>': apply, get

**`configuration` variable dump:**

```
{ listenerArn:
       OutputImpl {
         __pulumiOutput: true,
         resources: [Function],
         allResources: [Function],
         isKnown: Promise { <pending> },
         isSecret: Promise { <pending> },
         promise: [Function],
         toString: [Function],
         toJSON: [Function] },
      priority: 0,
      actions: [ { type: 'forward' } ],
      conditions: [ { pathPattern: [Object] } ] }
```

Where is the mistake?

Answer (score 1):

The issue is that you declare `conditions` as an object:

```
conditions: {},
```

but then try to put an array in it.

Also, inside the loop, your assignment

```
    conditions = [
        {[item]: {values: listener_rules_data[key][item]}}
    ]
```

will override the whole array every time. Did you mean to use `push`?

I'm not exactly sure the correct semantics of assigning values to conditions, but this is my approximation of the code:

```
for (var key in listener_rules_data) {
    const [fieldName, items] = Object.entries(listener_rules_data[key])[0];
    let configuration = {
        listenerArn: httpsListener.arn,
        priority: i,
        actions: [{
            type: "forward",
        }],
        conditions: [{ pathPattern: {values: items as string[]} }],
    }

    new aws.lb.ListenerRule(project_name + '-https-rule-' + i++, configuration);
}
```

For your configuration, it should set conditions to

```
[
  { pathPattern: { values: [ '/login/*', '/auth/*', '/info/*' ] } }
]
```

Comment: Good catch! Overwriting an array is correct though.

Comment: It produces wrong data: conditions: [ { values: 'hostHeader' }, { values: 'pathPattern' } ] }

Comment: I should be: 
conditions: [
        {
            pathPattern: {
                values: ["/foo"],
            },
        },
    ],